# FuelPHP SimpleAuth custom column name?

Tags: fuelphp

With SimpleAuth package, Im working on login function.
By default, user table is supposed to have a column "username".
But my system has a user table with "login_id" instead of "username".

```
Fuel\Core\Database_Exception [ 1054 ]:
Unknown column 'username' in 'where clause' 
[ SELECT * FROM `m_user` WHERE (`username` = 'admin' OR `email` = 'admin') 
AND `password` = 'mIIMXQgANGZ21XHRTpI2Krpla9yx3UwEw0PCNfjAN4I=' ]
```

I cannot figure out how it handles custom field name.
I tried configuration on APPPATH/config/simpleauth.php with "'username_post_key' => 'login_id'," which did not work..

Thanks in advance.

```
### APPPATH/config/auth.php ###
return array(
    'driver' => 'SimpleAuth',
    'verify_multiple_logins' => false,
    'salt' => 'techtech',
    'iterations' => 10000,
);

### APPPATH/config/simpleauth.php ###
<?php
    return array(

    'db_connection' => null,

    'table_name' => 'm_user',

    'table_columns' => array('*'),

    'guest_login' => true,

    'multiple_logins' => false,

    'remember_me' => array(

      'enabled' => false,

      'cookie_name' => 'rmcookie',

      'expiration' => 86400 * 31,
    ),

    'groups' => array(
    ),

    'roles' => array(
    ),

    'login_hash_salt' => 'tech_login',

    'username_post_key' => 'login_id',

    'password_post_key' => 'password',
    );


### user table ###
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| login_id       | varchar(100)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| first_name     | varchar(20)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name      | varchar(20)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password       | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_login_at  | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at     | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at     | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted_at     | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't configure it, because `username_post_key` is for POST field name, not for table column name. There is no configuration for table column name.

You must customize SimpleAuth, or create your own driver.

Comment: Wow, thank you for such a super quick answer!! All right, I will try a custom driver.